# Checking null for htmlnode collection using c#

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I am using html agility pack to parse the html using c#.

```
 HtmlNodeCollection hNodes = myHtmDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h1");
```

I am looping through this hNodes. And sometimes it may be null. So how to check whether hNodes is null or not. For string you can use IsNullOrEmpty. Like that here is there anything to check for null. I want result as

```
If (hNodes != null)
 DoSomething
```

Comment: Have you tried it? You'll find you've gotten it right!

Comment: if you want to check for not null and not empty list, use `(if (hNodes != null && hNodes.Any())` For null check only you'r ok (if in lower case)

Comment: Just now i tried. It works. Thank you all.. :)

Comment: hNodes.Any() is a new information for me. Thanks Raphael.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus HtmlAgilityPack HtmlNodeCollection is null if no matching nodes are found, sadly, so just a null check is all that is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is perfect, with that sentence you check for nullability of member.